# In Protractor, how do we iterate and give different values to the angular model with $index in it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I need to click a button thrice(that would give up three text boxes with the html code given below) and then give different values on each textbox appeared.

The code is used to click thrice is

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    element(by.id('protractor-type')).click();
};
```

And then three text boxes appeared.
The html code of textbox is

```
<input type="text" required="" ng-model="config.eTypes[$index]" ng-change="updateEySettings()" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="Eg: Dancing" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

I could give the value to only one textbox using the code

```
element(by.model('config.eTypes[$index]')).sendKeys('1st box');
```

But I need to give values on other textboxes too.

I unsuccessfully tried doing something like this

```
element.all(by.repeater('type in config.eTypes track by $index')).then(function(arr){
     arr[0].sendKeys('cat');
     arr[1].sendKeys('ball');
     arr[2].sendKeys('bat');
 });
```

Please suggest the appropriate and right way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over something in protractor use functions as they are reliable. `for()` loop usually executes much faster than protractor can click on the button. Here's how -

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    clickBtn(i);
}
function clickBtn(val){
    element(by.id('protractor-type')).click();

    //Assert the presence of the element that you want to verify on clicking of button. Here's a custom wait() function.
    browser.wait(function(){
        return element.all(by.model('config.eTypes[$index]')).then(function(arr){
            return arr.length === val;
        });
    });

    //You can send values to the input here if required.
};
```

This would click on the button 3 times and verify that 3 input elements are created each time it clicks. You can send the values with `.all()` function and i don't see a `ng-repeat` attribute on your element, so using `by.repeater` cannot be performed. Here's how -

```
element.all(by.model('config.eTypes[$index]')).then(function(arr){
     arr[0].sendKeys('cat');
     arr[1].sendKeys('ball');
     arr[2].sendKeys('bat');
 });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Amazing.. Thank you Mr.Girish, that worked like a charm